# $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$, show that $f$ is or injective or zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

Let $f\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}))$ such that:

$\forall(A,B)\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$

How can I show that **$f$ is or injective or the null function** ?

What I have tried so far haven't worked at all.

---

Notations : $\mathcal{L}(E)$ : set of the endomorphisms $E\rightarrow E$

Comment: Let me get this straight:  in the first line, you meant $f \in \mathcal L(\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R))$, right?  So $f$ is a *linear homomorphism* from $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$ to itself, right?  Where $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$ is the algebra of real $n \times n$ matrices, right?

Comment: Could you explain your notation?

Comment: You mean that $f$ is either the null function or injective?

Comment: What *have* you tried?

Comment: @RobertLewis Typo, sorry. You're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is not injective, so there is $A \ne 0$ such that $f(A) = 0$.  Then $f$ is $0$ on the two-sided ideal $J$ generated by $A$.  I claim that this ideal is all of $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$.  Suppose $A u \ne 0$.  Then if $P$ is 
a projection on the span of $u$, $AP \in J$ has rank $1$.  By multiplying on the left and right by suitable matrices, we get that all $E_{ij} \in J$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and $0$ everywhere else.
But by taking linear combinations of these, we can get all $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$.

BTW, there's nothing special about $\mathbb R$: this would work over any field.

Comment: I don't know anything about ideals, is there a way to do it without them ?

Comment: The two-sided ideal generated by $A$ is the linear span of the matrices $BAC$ for $B, C \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: What is $u$ there ? As you talk about its span, I guess it's a linear application, but then what is $Au$ ? How do you multiply a matrice and a lin application ?

Comment: No, $u$ is a vector.

Comment: A vector of what vector space ? $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: No, $\mathbb R^n$.